# Firewall and NAT settings in GSM modem for one server

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall, nat

I have a GSM Modem (PSI-MODEM-GSM/ETH) in field with one device behind, acting as a server. The situation is as follows:

```
         "PC"
          | \_________Dynamic IP: 10.103.153.122
          |
      (Internet )
     (Private APN)
      ( GSM Net.)
          |
          |  _________Static IP 10.100.10.10
          | /
       GSM-Modem
        [ETH]
          | \_________DHCP-Server + Gateway
          |           192.168.0.1
          |
          |  _________
          | /         192.168.0.20 (Static via DHCP)
       [ETH 1]
       "Server"
```

The Configuration in the GSM modem is:

*Firewall*

[image: Firewall settings]

*NAT*

[image: NAT settings]

But I can not reach the device via `10.100.10.10:8443`. The route to the GSM modem is allright as I can reach its web-frontend via `10.100.10.10:80`. The log file of the modem shows

```
Apr 17 08:51:43 kernel: IN=ppp0 OUT=eth0 SRC=10.103.153.122 DST=192.168.0.20 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=119 ID=25050 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=51506 DPT=8443 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
Apr 17 08:51:43 kernel: IN=ppp0 OUT=eth0 SRC=10.103.153.122 DST=192.168.0.20 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=119 ID=25051 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=51507 DPT=8443 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
Apr 17 08:51:43 kernel: IN=ppp0 OUT=eth0 SRC=10.103.153.122 DST=192.168.0.20 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=119 ID=25052 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=51508 DPT=8443 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
Apr 17 08:51:44 kernel: IN=ppp0 OUT=eth0 SRC=10.103.153.122 DST=192.168.0.20 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=119 ID=25053 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=51506 DPT=8443 WINDOW=68 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
Apr 17 08:51:44 kernel: IN=ppp0 OUT=eth0 SRC=10.103.153.122 DST=192.168.0.20 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=119 ID=25054 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=51507 DPT=8443 WINDOW=68 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
Apr 17 08:51:44 kernel: IN=ppp0 OUT=eth0 SRC=10.103.153.122 DST=192.168.0.20 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=119 ID=25055 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=51508 DPT=8443 WINDOW=68 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
Apr 17 08:51:44 kernel: IN=ppp0 OUT=eth0 SRC=10.103.153.122 DST=192.168.0.20 LEN=428 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=119 ID=25056 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=51506 DPT=8443 WINDOW=68 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
Apr 17 08:51:45 kernel: IN=ppp0 OUT=eth0 SRC=10.103.153.122 DST=192.168.0.20 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=119 ID=25057 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=51506 DPT=8443 WINDOW=68 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
Apr 17 08:51:45 kernel: IN=ppp0 OUT=eth0 SRC=10.103.153.122 DST=192.168.0.20 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=119 ID=25058 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=51506 DPT=8443 WINDOW=68 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0
```

*Question:* I call `10.103.153.122:8443` from `10.103.153.122`. Why is the firewall not accepting the packages?